# slickGrid check row programmatically

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have the rowSelectionModel and the checkBox plugin's set.

How can I check to see if a checkbox is clicked on a row and check a checkbox on another row?

Comment: post some code sample...

Answer (score 0):

The "subscribe" is a most suitable event for you, and you will have a function where you can use jquery to refer to another row

Documentation is pretty clear about it. Example is below.

```
gridInstance.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e,args){
     //use e, and args to get detais about cell was clicked and in which row is it
     $(".another-row .anotherRow").attr('clicked', true);
});
```

define class anotherRow for column in column options, which contains checkbox suppose to be changed programmatically.

I did this first time, in the same kind of problem. I wrote the dummy function and subscribe to the event

```
gridInstance.onCellChange.subsribe(function(e, args){
    window.e = e;
    window.args = args;
});
```

here, you can examine "e" and "args" objects, until you will understand where you are, and what to do next. Once you will understand delete those lines.